# Getting Value Error in python code

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I am getting a value error in function nm_model but the value is correct for A2 in forward_propagation function i don't understand why am i getting this error.

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(0, num_iterations):

    # Forward propagation. Inputs: "X, parameters". Outputs: "A2, cache".
    A2, cache = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
```

I am getting error here 
This is my error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-7a346e8aefff> in <module>()
      1 X_assess, Y_assess = nn_model_test_case()
----> 2 parameters = nn_model(X_assess, Y_assess, 4, num_iterations=10000, print_cost=True)
      3 print("W1 = " + str(parameters["W1"]))
      4 print("b1 = " + str(parameters["b1"]))
      5 print("W2 = " + str(parameters["W2"]))

<ipython-input-131-e266bdc33aa9> in nn_model(X, Y, n_h, num_iterations, print_cost)
     33         ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 4 lines of code)
     34         # Forward propagation. Inputs: "X, parameters". Outputs: "A2, cache".
---> 35         A2, cache = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
     36 
     37         # Cost function. Inputs: "A2, Y, parameters". Outputs: "cost".

<ipython-input-129-32057a9db96b> in forward_propagation(X, parameters)
     21     # Implement Forward Propagation to calculate A2 (probabilities)
     22     ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 4 lines of code)
---> 23     Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
     24     A1 = np.tanh(Z1)
     25     Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2

ValueError: shapes (4,6) and (2,3) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your forward_propigation method, your taking the dot product of arrays W1 and X. This corrisponds to matrix multiplication as your using 2d arrays. The dimensions of these arrays are not correct for the dot product operation, hence the error.

Comment: I found the error it was in initialization of X. I was using x.size. I corrected using x.shape[0]. But i don't understand x.shape and x.size work similarly.

Comment: X.size returns the number of elements in the array X, rather than the width or hight ect

Answer (score 0):

The error was in initializing X. I used X.size for initialization instead when i tried X.shape[0] It worked fine.